# Convergence to $0$ of a certain series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was wondering whether or not the following holds - I didn't manage to get anywhere using standard tricks from elementary analysis. $$\lim_{c\to\infty}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}}ce^{-n-\frac{c}{n}}=0.$$
Or I suppose equivalently $$\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_1^\infty ce^{-x-\frac{c}{x}}\mathrm{d}x=0.$$
Many thanks!

Comment: Try dominated convergence theorem on your sum.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Thanks, but what do you suggest dominating with?

Comment: Assuming $c$ is an integer, for any $n$, $ce^{-n-\frac{c}{n}} \leq ce^{-\sqrt{c}-\frac{c}{\sqrt{c}}}\leq  ce^{-\sqrt{c}}$ and $\sum_{c}ce^{-\sqrt{c}}$ converges. The first inequality follows from some calculus: the function $x\to e^{-x-\frac{c}{x}}$ achieves its maximum at $x:=\sqrt{c}$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I don't think that's quite right - isn't it the case that the dominating function cannot depend on $c$? We are taking the limit in $c$; so the dominating function can only depend on $n$ I am still unable to find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does converge to zero. Making the change of variable $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$, the integral becomes
$$\int_1^\infty ce^{-x}e^{-c/x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1c\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}e^{-cx}\mathrm{d}x,$$

then note that $\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and use dominated convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $c$ large enough, $$\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\left(1/c+1\right)x}dx = -\frac{ce^{-\left(1/c+1\right)}}{c+1}$$
(use the substitution rule with $u=-(1/c+1)x$). The rest is easy.

Having said that, the limit you ask about is not zero (it is $\infty$). [Wolfram agrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BIntegrate%5Bc*Exp%5B-x-x%2Fc%5D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D%2Cc-%3EInfinity%5D).

Alternatively, you
could convince yourself that the integral above converges (for finite $c$ large enough) and then just
use power series and integrate term-by-term, if you do not want to use the substitution rule.

Comment: I believe you meant to use $\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} e^{-x-\frac{c}{x}}\,dx$ ..

Comment: @par Thanks, but you've shown the result for the integrand $ce^{-x-\frac{x}{c}}$ I believe? It should be $ce^{-x-\frac{c}{x}}$.